# How do I fix a sorting issue not related to numerical sorting in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, sorting

I'm familiar with numerical sorting where the issue is a number as a value or a string. I'm asking a different question.

I'd like to sort files in a way such that the file that includes a string after the main file name comes AFTER the main file name. An example of what I want:

```
Truck.docx
Truck - maintenance.docx
Truck - supplies.docx
```

However, Windows sorts this with the main file on the bottom:

```
Truck - maintennace.docx
Truck - supplies.docx
Truck.docx
```

This produces kind of a messy sort. I know I've seen this sorted "properly" in other places, perhaps in Android or MacOS.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: `space` sorts before `.` so I don't think this is fixable.

Comment: Technically, a shell extension could introduce a new column that could control the sort however it wants assuming that you sort on that column.  I not aware of any such extension.

Comment: The best solution may be to rename the other files with no spaces on either side of the dash.

Comment: What I am hoping for is that Explorer will learn to sort on file names and not extensions. I can't really change the spacing of the dashes because there are dashes that have no spacing for different reasons.

Comment: So, I found where this does sort correctly. When I look at my files on One Drive on my Android phone everything is as it should be. I often find in curious that these kinds of discrepancies go on for decades.

Comment: "I can't really change the spacing of the dashes because there are dashes that have no spacing for different reasons." add a space to the first file then "Truck .docx"

Answer (score 1):

Using NirSoft's nifty utility [`PropertySystemView`](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_property_system_view.html), I found that the FileInfo type has a property that doesn't map to a visible coluumn: `System.ItemNameDisplayWithoutExtension`. However, it can be specified as the sorting property for an open **Explorer** window programatically via the `shell.application` com object. For a quick demo, open **Explorer** to the folder with the files in quesiton and, for the sake of demo code simplicity, make sure it's the only **Explorer** window open. Then:

1. Open a **PowerShell** console window.
2. Copy & paste the following command:

   ```
   @((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows())[0].Document.SortColumns = 'prop:System.ItemNameDisplayWithoutExtension;'
   ```
3. Check your **Explorer** window

Before (sort by Name):
[image]

After:
[image]

Now, the relatively good news. Even though the sort has to be applied by code, if you close the window, the sort setting will be saved for that folder (assuming saved views are working properly). But if you apply a different sort when the folder is open, you can't revert to custom sort via the UI, you have to execute the code again. But you can safely apply secondary, tertiary, and quaternary sort criteria by successive <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>MouseClick</kbd> on the desired column header(s).

However, when the window is displayed with your custom sort, you also have the option of saving the current view settings as a custom default for all folders *that use the current folder's `FolderType`* (Generic, Documents, Music, etc.) by using `Apply to Folders`:

[image]

I can think of a few more obscure ways this could be easily available to multiple folders, but this should at least get you started, and custom defaults for Generic and/or Documents may be all you need.

---

### Edit: Further testing reveals...:

- This mod can only be applied to file-system folders (directories). Attempting to apply to virtual folders that contain file-system items (Quick Access, SearchResults, Libraries) or compression files that display as folders (.zip, .cab, .rar) fail with the error:

```
Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))
```

- The demo code was wirtten to be a quick, simple proof-of-concept, but it's crude in that it wipes out existing sort criteria --- a better approach would be to only modidfy the sort when `System.ItemNameDisplay` is already specified as a sort criterion, and to do so by replacing it with `System.ItemNameDisplayWithoutExtension` while leaving any other criteria intact. This modified code will work with multiple **Explorer** windows open, and limiting itself to the restrrictions I've described:

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()) | %{
    If ( $_.Document.Folder.Self.IsFileSystem -and -not $_.Document.Folder.Self.IsBrowsable )
    {
        $NewSort = $_.Document.SortColumns -replace ('\.ItemNameDisplay;','.ItemNameDisplayWithoutExtension;')
        $_.Document.SortColumns = $NewSort
    }
}
```

So if you want to apply this as widely as possible:

1. Assuming default FolderTypes are in effect, open the user folders under `This PC` as they each use a different FolderType:

   - Desktop (General/Generic)
   - Documents (Documents)
   - Downloads (Downloads)
   - Music
   - Pictures
   - Videos
2. Copy and paste the above code into a **PowerShell** console window and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute.
3. THen, with each folder:

   - Set any other view settings to your preferred default for that FolderType.
   - From the `View` ribbon, execute `Apply to Folders`, accepting confirmation dialogs.
   - Close the folder.

Comment: Wow! This is super comprehensive. I'll try this and see what happens. Thank you for such a thorough teaching!

Comment: You're welcome. Please post back when you've had a cancee to try. I've seen posts for years from those annoyed by the fact that `FileName.ext` sorts after `FileName (Copy 1).ext`, but only reccelntly delved into the property system. Then your post inspred  me to start poking around there. So your the proud new Beta tester of a brand-new tweak! :D Hope your results mirror mine.